# Bits tricks and magic

Tags: c++, bit

I'm writing a program in C++, and it has to be as minimal as possible. I need some help with an if/else statement. This is the code:

```
if (lines & 1 << ((d & 1) * 30 + 5 * l + c)) {
    cout << "Invalid";
} else {
    lines |= 1 << ((d & 1) * 30 + 5 * l + c);
}
```

What i'm doing here is: verifing if a bit is set to 1 and I cout something, and if it's not, i'll set it to 1. Is there any way i can combine the 2 lines where i verify and where i set bit to 1 in the if body?

```
lines & 1 << ((d & 1) * 30 + 5 * l + c)
lines |= 1 << ((d & 1) * 30 + 5 * l + c)
```

I'm imagining something like:

```
if (lines |= .... )
```

And what it should do is: verify if bit is 1 and entering the if body, and if it's not(or it is already) make it 1.

Sorry for my poor english and this stupid request, but i can't figure out a way to do it and it drives me crazy.

P.S: Is there any site/calculator that can give me an boolean formula when i enter an equasion? ex: 3 .. .. = -1. and i need the operand and operator here.

Comment: Why do you want to combine the two lines in the if body?

Comment: What about a ternary operator

Comment: @jpo38 i want it to be as minimal as posible, when it comes to characters.

Comment: @chbchb55 i know and have used ternary operators, but i can't figure it out how to use it here, could you help me with the code?

Comment: Chcek out my answer @aleeN1

Comment: Are you allowed to mess with the bit otherwise? For example, can you set the bit to zero in the invalid case?

Comment: @aleeN1: ` i want it to be as minimal as possible` Let the compiler do that if needed

Comment: @MadPhysicist in the invalid case i do nothing to the "lines" variable, but i can make it 1 (it is already 1) so i can unite the 2 code lines into 1. hope you understand what i say.

Comment: @jpo38. OP means in terms of character count. Think code golf.

Comment: As for the site/calculator, it is entirely unclear what you want, and `ex: 3 .. .. = -1.` is totally *not* an example of anything, but to cut a long story short, if [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) does not do it, then it is unlikely that anyone else does it.

Comment: @aleeN1. I am assuming this is part of a larger code. Can I toggle the bit instead of making it 1?

Comment: If you want to reduce the number of lines of code, the best and easiest way is to delete your linefeeds, thus putting all your statements in one line.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it is a very short code, actually those lines are the bigger ones, that's why i want to shorten them. No, you can't toggle it, because if it's 1 it remains 1, for further test cases. If the ith bit is 1, it means the ith stick was used. So i can't use that stick for the remaining of the program.

Comment: the less you type now the harder it will be for you in one month to understand the code. Too much code isnt good but there is a limit where reducing it more mainly hurts readability. Imho you are already far beyond that limit when you have 4 magic numbers in a single line.

Comment: @MikeNakis spaces/new lines/tabs are not included in the number of characters. it's just about digits, letters and other signs used in c++.

Comment: @tobi303 i know that. this is a contest where the one who makes the program working with the least amount of characters wins. it's not for production or anything. it's kinda just 4fun.

Comment: What are `lines`, `d`, `l`, and `c`'s definitions

Comment: @aleeN1. You may want to check out https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (lines == (lines|= mask)) cout << "Invalid";
```

Comment: Isn't this undefined behavior?

Comment: @MikeNakis: why should it ?

Comment: because you are both modifying and reading a variable in the same statement.

Comment: I am not saying that I know for sure that this is undefined behavior, but I have the feeling that it is.

Comment: I think this is pretty well defined, but won't work because evaluation order is left to right.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: absolutely, my bad.

Comment: Basically, lines will always be equal to itself after the assignment. I used `^=` instead of `|=` in my answer to get around this.

Comment: it is indeed UB.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: `^=` won't have the same effect, as it will clear the bit when it was set, whereas the original code leaves it unchanged.

Comment: Right. OP just clarified that, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: It's perfect. I love you guys ;* .

Comment: @aleeN1 beware: "undefined behavior" means that it may work in a certain way with your compiler, but with a different compiler, or even with a different version of the same compiler, you might get an entirely different thing, like a bowl of petunias.

Comment: @MikeNakis: in the real world, the only alternative is performing the assignment before the comparison, which will always yield a true result. The standard details the evaluation rules http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order, which I am totally desperate to successfully check here.